# UISlider with increments of 5

Tags: iphone, ios, uislider

How do I have my `UISlider` go from `1-100` in increments of `5`?

Answer (score 169):

Add a target like this:

```
slider.continuous = YES;
[slider addTarget:self
      action:@selector(valueChanged:) 
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And in the valueChanged function set the value to the closest value that is divisible by 5.

```
[slider setValue:((int)((slider.value + 2.5) / 5) * 5) animated:NO];
```

---

So if you need any interval other than 5 simply set it like so:

```
float interval = 5.0f;//set this
[slider setValue:interval*floorf((slider.value/interval)+0.5f) animated:NO];
```

Comment: I feel honestly stupid. It's always the simple things that get me.

Comment: Thanks, avoid me thinking to much about it ^^ I did do a slight change however: int increment = 10;
    [numberOfAppsInFutur setValue:((int)((numberOfAppsInFutur.value + increment/2.) / increment) * increment) animated:NO];

Comment: In case it helps, there is a complete example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8219848/168594).

Answer (score 71):

A slightly more elegant solution in Swift could be something like this

```
let step: Float = 5
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
  let roundedValue = round(sender.value / step) * step
  sender.value = roundedValue
  // Do something else with the value

}
```

This way you get steps of 5. You can read more about the setup in my [post](http://web.archive.org/web/20170506161624/http://candycode.io/uislider-with-steps-snapping-to-values-in-swift/).

Comment: Link gets to a site with ad only

Answer (score 10):

There is another way to active the stepper functionality. works in a general case

Example:

range of data is 0 - 2800  and I want the increments to be in 25 unit values.  I would do the following

1. set up the range of the slider to be 0 - (maxRange/unitsteps).
2. when the value changed method runs use  (int)slider.value * unitsteps .

in the example above my slider would be set in IB to range   0 - 112.
and my code would be     (int)slider.value * 25.

if you then have a text field that can be modified for direct input you would just do the opposite set the slider value to the [textfield.text intValue]/ unitsteps.

Comment: a side effect of this is that it can help enforce limits to the textfield value...

Comment: This seemed perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone looking for the Swift syntax...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mySlider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderValueDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
}

func sliderValueDidChange(sender:UISlider!)
{
    //Set value to the nearest 5...
    print((Float)((Int)((sender.value + 2.5) / 5) * 5))
    sender.setValue((Float)((Int)((sender.value + 2.5) / 5) * 5), animated: false)
}
```

Alternatively, just create an Action function with the Assistant Editor (what I did ultimately)...

```
@IBAction func mySliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    //Set value to the nearest int
    sender.setValue(Float(roundf(sender.value)), animated: false)

}
```

Answer (score 7):

In swift 3, slider with increments +/- 7:

```
@IBOutlet weak var sldComponent: UISlider!
```

...

```
sldComponent.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(_sldComponentChangedValue),for: .valueChanged)
```

...

```
func _sldComponentChangedValue(sender: UISlider!) {

        self.sldComponent.setValue((round(sender.value / 7) * 7), animated: false)
        print("\(sender.value)")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
@IBAction func onSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let value = Int(sender.value)
    if value % 5 == 0 {
        // handle(value) ... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
1. In storyboard mode, drag and drop a stepper and label.  the label will show the stepper values.
```

2. left click and drag both label and stepper to your view controller as outlets.

name label as "stepperValue"

3. drag and drop stepper again making it a func- I called mine "func"

@IBAction func inc(sender: AnyObject) {
            stepperValue.text = "(Int(stepper.value) * 5 )"

click the stepper and it will increment by 5