# Assigning value points to a Slider in Swift UI

Tags: swiftui, slider

I want to have a slider that steps in to some distinct values where the increments are not constant. For example I have list of Doubles

```
 @Published var allDurations:[Double] = [20,50,100,110,1000]
```

I want the slider to step into each value on that list exactly and the slider to equally distribute these values throughout the slider regardless of what the value is. So basically the user can only pick from these 5 values from the list. Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: this is in UIKit, but will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8219848/3970488

Comment: Thank You Aswath. I was able to use the same concept from that and use that in Swift UI.