# How to control UISlider in ios

Tags: ios, slider, uislider

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UISlider with increments of 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519460/uislider-with-increments-of-5)

How to create slider and sliding the values increased by 10,20,30... & decreased by -10,-20,-30...in this format. help any other links for tutorial or source code. Advance in thanks

Comment: `UISlider` as is does not provide 'step' functionality - you'll have to subclass it (or add a delegate method to the class that uses it).

Answer (score 0):

```
UISlider* mySlider = [[UISlider alloc] init];
mySlider.minimumValue = -30.0f;
mySlider.maximumValue = 30.0f;  

-(IBAction) sliderChanged:(id) sender{

      UISlider *slider = (UISlider *) sender;
      int progressAsInt =(int)(slider.value + 0.5f);
      NSString *newText =[[NSString alloc]
                      initWithFormat:@"%d",progressAsInt];
      self.sliderLabel.text = newText;
}
```

Comment: OP is asking about a slider with +/-10 increments/decrements...