# how to set uislider value with 0.5 interval

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

Having a UISLider with min value 5 and max value 10 how can I show the value range with 0.5 interval in uilabel

```
_ie.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f",(_Iel.value)];
```

Comment: Use "steps", like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519460/uislider-with-increments-of-5 just adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can round like this:

```
_ie.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f",(roundf(_Iel.value * 2.0) * 0.5)];
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you are using this, mark correct answer please.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for 0.5 or any other interval

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    self.increment = 0.5f;
    float roundedSliderValue = roundf(self.theSlider.value / self.increment) * self.increment;
    _ie.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f",roundedSliderValue];
}
```