# How can i make a UISlider with step value

Tags: xcode, swift, uislider

Hope someone can help me. Im trying to make a UISlider with step value from 1 to 5 in Swift

My code are:

```
@IBAction func yearChange(sender: UISlider) {

    let step: Float = 1
    let currentValue = round(sender.value / step) * step
    print("\(currentValue) year")

}
```

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519460/uislider-with-increments-of-5
Just change the 5 as 1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i solved the issue with this code :

```
let step: Float = 1
let roundedValue = round(sender.value / step) * step
sender.value = roundedValue
```

Comment: where should I add this steps code if I have slider added in storyboard?

Comment: Make an IBAction for the slider for the event ValueChanged. and put it in there.

Answer (score 0):

hope this help

```
let slider = UISlider()
let total: Float = 5
slider.maximumValue = total
slider.minimumValue = 1

@IBAction func yearChange(sender: UISlider) {
    
    let step: Float = 1
    let currentValue = round((sender.value - sender.minimumValue) / step)
    print("\(currentValue) year")
    
}
```

Comment: How do i get the slider to move in steps when im seleting af period ?

Comment: sorry, what does ` seleting af period` mean?