# How to show the step progress bar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a demo project for showing form progress. I mean, as the user fills the form in four steps, I want to show the progress of each of the user's step.

For better understanding please have a look on the screenshot that follows.

[image: Step Progress]

I want to create something like the above screen shot. So please suggest me. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

I can't use UISlider, because it's not possible to create four thumbs in one UISlider.

Thanks in Advance... :)

Comment: You can try using library:
https://cocoapods.org/?q=step%20pro

Comment: @nynohu .... Thanks for this link.... :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UISlider with increments of 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519460/uislider-with-increments-of-5)

Comment: I fond this it might be helpful: https://github.com/amratab/FlexibleSteppedProgressBar

Comment: https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ui-controls/xamarin-stepprogressbar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options but the two components I found the most easy and complete are both the [FlexibleSteppedProgressBar](https://github.com/amratab/FlexibleSteppedProgressBar) and the [Progress-Indicator-Swift](https://github.com/AstroDan/Progress-Indicator-Swift). The first is very complete but the second is simple and clean for basic usage.

You can choose the best based on your needs.

Comment: is there any vertical step indiactor library.

Comment: Hello @JatinVashisht I've search and could not find one. I saw you already posted in FlexibleSteppedProgressBar asking for support. Let's see what they say.

Comment: Thanks for the search, yes i have posted on FlexibleSteppedProgressBar, waiting for the Answer from them.

Comment: @FelipePlets can you suggest one with carthage support?

Comment: @KanishkGuptaI don't use Carthage myself, but I saw someone asked for Carthage support on the FlexibleSteppedProgressBar: https://github.com/amratab/FlexibleSteppedProgressBar/issues/13