# How to make UISlider 300 values easier to use?

Tags: ios, uislider

Are there any ways to make UISlider with 300 values to be easier to use? It's hard to pick the right value since the step between them is so small.

I know I could use other elements like UIPicker but slider works better for my case except it's hard to pick the right value.

Reducing the number of values available is also not a solution.

Making a slider go full screen on 3d touch is an option it 3d is not available on all the iPhones and I'm also not sure how to implement that.

Comment: *"slider works better for my case except it's hard to pick the right value"* - that's a contradiction. If it's hard to pick the right value then it does not work better for your case.

Comment: Picker also works but it has another downside - I can't get a value when picker is scrolling.

Comment: I found this with a simple google search. It was the first result. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519460/uislider-with-increments-of-5

Comment: Thanks user3344977, I've seen it. I didn't want to skip values by scrolling in larger increments. I needed a user to be able to select any value in 0-300 range easily. Something like zoom-in on scroll when he starts to scroll or 3d touch would probably work but for now I switched to UIPicker.